# jsonobj.key name is not returning full value of its corresponding key

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, servlets, javascript-objects

we are passing json object from jsp servlet page as a json response.

Json Object serverside that we are passing :

```
[{"name":"Ravi Kumar","dob":"29-feb-1962","address":"abc building, xyz road pqr city"},{"name":"Rakesh Kumar","dob":"26-feb-1952","address":"mks building, efg road mno city"}]
```

servlet side code example :

```
 {
              response.setCont`enter code here`entType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
             PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 
                pw.print(jsonArray);
                pw.close();
    }
```

and Javascript side :

```
{
var person= xmlhttp.responseText;

                var jsonPerson = JSON.parse(person);

                for (var i = 0; i < jsonPerson .length; i++) {
                    var jsonEachPerson=jsonPerson [i];

alert("name : " + jsonEachPerson.name + " dob : " + jsonEachPerson.dob + " address : " + jsonEachPerson.address)
}
```

if we have string without blank space then its fine but if we have **blank space** we are getting only **first value** before space ex for **Ravi Kumar** we are getting only **Ravi** and for RaviKumar we are getting Ravikumar.

if we are printing "person" then i am getting same value what ever we are passing from servlet.

Comment: can you share the output of this line of code `var person= xmlhttp.responseText;`?

Comment: I guess you fat fingered a `shit+enter` in the middle of the server side snippet.

Comment: Hi @ArnelAves Aves, Thank you for reply , out put of `var person= xmlhttp.responseText;` is the same as server side output `[{"name":"Ravi Kumar","dob":"29-feb-1962","address":"abc building, xyz road pqr city"},{"name":"Rakesh Kumar","dob":"26-feb-1952","address":"mks building, efg road mno city"}]`

Comment: this code is working fine on my side

Comment: @ArnelAves yes I also checked its printing correct value in alert box  but while printing in input field its printing only first value. below is jquery code `$('#person tbody')
        .append( '<td style="width:18%;"><input type="text" name="person Name" value='
            + jsonEachPerson.name
            + '></td>'`

Answer (score 0):

you just a missing " on this part of your code `value=' + jsonEachPerson.name + '`, values need to be enclosed in **quotation marks** see updated code below:

```
 $('#person tbody') .append( '<td style="width:18%;"><input type="text" name="person Name" value="' + jsonEachPerson.name + '"></td>');
```